# Merging Duplicate Columns in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a task where i have to get an aggregate of the items sold. 
Currently i am getting

```
salesOrder  Item    QtyOrdered  
1            1          6
2            1          5
3            1          2
4            6          5
```

What i want is

```
Item        QtyOrdered  
1               13
6                5
```

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: You forgot to include the code you wrote that doesn't produce your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple query using `SUM()` and `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT Item, SUM(QtyOrdered) QtyOrdered
FROM Table
GROUP BY Item;
```

Comment: @iam_em Please [read and follow this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)